# Is ok to use a CMOS Analog multiplexer with voltage from a sensor as an input?

Tags: sensor, analog, multiplexer, light-sensor

So, I got an analog circuit with an IR sensor that generates a voltage in output. The voltage is a measure that must be read with a microcontroller (I use Arduino Zero). [This](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/948/Pyreos-Analog-TO-Sensor-One-Channel-Datasheet-1509531.pdf) is the sensor.

As you may see from the datasheet, they suggest using a TSV991 in output.

[image: sensor + TSV991 circuit]

Now, because I would like to use multiple sensors and one analog input on the Arduino, I came up with the idea of using an analog multiplexer. I found out [this](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4734.pdf), the MAX4734 that seems very good for my application (the vary low power consumption is a must for me).

Now, I was wondering if, using such a device to select the input on the analog port could impact on the actual voltage I need to measure from the sensor. I was told to check also the max current the multiplexer can accept to avoid any damage or malfunction. According to the datasheet it "handles rail-to-rail analog signals" so, it should be ok, am I right?

Comment: the analog mux will have varying resistance; is that a problem/

Comment: And, are there devices that can handle output from sensors?

Comment: this is a noninverting preamp which should have very high impedance, switch resistance should not be an issue. But the sensor is powered from +5V, mux only handles 4V absolute max, this might be a problem.

Comment: So long as you put the multiplexer after the TSV991 op-amp this should work OK.

Comment: @dmb The power supply is not a problem as soon as we use 6.6V (2 batteries at 3.3V) as a standard for the whole circuit.

Comment: @SteveG yeah, the idea is to put it after the OP-AMP.